# Increment score in a quiz game based on selecting the right answers with an object array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

I am still fairly new to JS and don't know how to write the code to increase score based on answering correctly in this quiz game. My goal is to add 100 for every correct answer and if you answer incorrectly you simply don't get any points so the points will remain the same based off your last correct answer. I will leave in the last code I tried but didn't succeed in.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn');
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn');
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container');
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question');
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons');
const scoreTracker = document.getElementById('score-tracker');



let randomQuestions, currentQuestionIndex;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentQuestionIndex++
    setNextQuestion()
});

function startGame() {
    startButton.classList.add('hide');
    randomQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide');
    scoreTracker.classList.remove('hide');
    setNextQuestion();
};

function setNextQuestion() {
    resetState()
    showQuestion(randomQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]);
};

function showQuestion(question) {
    questionElement.innerText = question.question;
    question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = answer.text;
        button.classList.add('btn');
        if (answer.correct) {
            button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
        }
        button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer);
        answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    })
};

function resetState() {
    clearStatusClass(document.body);
    nextButton.classList.add('hide');
    while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
        answerButtonsElement.removeChild
        (answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
    }
};

/* Checks if selected button is part of the correct dataset */
function selectAnswer(e) {
    const selectedButton = e.target;
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
    setStatusClass(document.body, correct);
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
        setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (randomQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        startButton.innerText = 'Restart';
        startButton.classList.remove('hide');
    }
};

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    clearStatusClass(element);
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('wrong');
    }
};

function clearStatusClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct');
    element.classList.remove('wrong');
};


/* Game questions with 4 total choices */
let questions = [
    {
        question: 'What year did the Raiders win their last Super Bowl?',
        answers: [
            { text: '2002', correct: true },
            { text: '1993', correct: false },
            { text: '1983', correct: false },
            { text: '1972', correct: false },
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What was Jack Tatum's nickname?",
        answers: [
            { text: 'Killer Croc', correct: false },
            { text: 'The Assassin', correct: true },
            { text: 'The Jackhammer', correct: false },
            { text: 'Killer Bee', correct: false },
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "Which 'Hall of Fame' Raider wore the number 00",
        answers: [
            { text: 'Charles Woodson', correct: false },
            { text: 'Kenny Stabler', correct: false },
            { text: 'Mike Haynes' , correct: false },
            { text: 'Jim Otto', correct: true },

        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Which Raider became a HollyWood star?',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Carl Weathers', correct: true },
            { text: 'Howie Long', correct: false },
            { text: 'Lyle Alzado', correct: false },
            { text: 'Bo Jackson', correct: false },
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Who is Al Davis?',
        answers: [
            { text: 'Current star Wie Receiver', correct: false},
            { text: 'Current Owner', correct: false },
            { text: "QB from the late 70's", correct: false },
            { text: 'Ex Owner', correct: true },
        ]
    },
];

const scoreUp = document.getElementById('score-up');
scoreUpNow = 0;

questions.forEach(function(index) {
    if(index.value == true) {
        scoreUp += 100;
    } else {
        scoreUp += 0;
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Iceberg&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Iceberg', cursive;
}

/* 3 chosen variable colors that will be distributed for the game. For answer selection 
(each a color for right and wrong answers) */
:root{
    --hue-neutral: 213;
    --hue-wrong: 283;
    --hue-correct: 190;
}

body {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 31%, 19%);
} 

/* When answer is correct this color will become visible upon the backround selection to match correct answer */
body.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
}
/* When answer is incorrect this color will become visible upon the background selection to match wrong answer */
body.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}

/* Container layout */
.container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: #63768d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

/* top to bottom grid with 4 options to choose from when answering question */
.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 20%, 70%);
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: #b8f3ff;
}

/* if this button chose is 'correct' then this variable color will display */
.btn.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 80%);
}

/* if this button chose is 'incorrect' then this variable color will display */
.btn.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 80%);
}

/* dimensiosn for start and next button*/
.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

/* Layout for buttons*/
.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* grid layout for score system */
.score-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* hide selection when it is unnecessary to have visible*/
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script defer src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Raider Quiz Game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Container for questions and 4 options to choose from-->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--A start game button and a next button when anwering questions-->
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Are you a hardcore Raiders fan?<br>Find Out!</button>
            <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div id="score-tracker" class="score-grid hide">
            <h3>Score</h3>
            <div id="score-up">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You were almost there, just a few things were left to do. To make it work as per your task, I did the following:

1. save the reference to the score in a var to be able to refer to it later;
2. introduce a function `processResults` whose responsibility is to update the results in the markup in case if the answer is correct;
3. run `processResults` every time the answer button is clicked.

You can run the code to see if it works. Well, it should :)

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn');
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn');
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container');
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question');
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons');
const scoreTracker = document.getElementById('score-tracker');
const scoreUpElement = document.getElementById('score-up');


let randomQuestions, currentQuestionIndex;

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
});

function startGame() {
  startButton.classList.add('hide');
  randomQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide');
  scoreTracker.classList.remove('hide');
  setNextQuestion();
  scoreUpElement.textContent = 0;
};

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState();
  showQuestion(randomQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]);
};

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question;
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = answer.text;
    button.classList.add('btn');
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer);
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
};

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body);
  nextButton.classList.add('hide');
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
};

/* Checks if selected button is part of the correct dataset */
function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target;
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct;
  
  processResults(correct);
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct);

  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })

  if (randomQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    startButton.innerText = 'Restart';
    startButton.classList.remove('hide');
  }
};

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element);
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct');
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong');
  }
};

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct');
  element.classList.remove('wrong');
};


/* Game questions with 4 total choices */
let questions = [{
    question: 'What year did the Raiders win their last Super Bowl?',
    answers: [{
        text: '2002',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: '1993',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: '1983',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: '1972',
        correct: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What was Jack Tatum's nickname?",
    answers: [{
        text: 'Killer Croc',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'The Assassin',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: 'The Jackhammer',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Killer Bee',
        correct: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "Which 'Hall of Fame' Raider wore the number 00",
    answers: [{
        text: 'Charles Woodson',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Kenny Stabler',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Mike Haynes',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Jim Otto',
        correct: true
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Which Raider became a HollyWood star?',
    answers: [{
        text: 'Carl Weathers',
        correct: true
      },
      {
        text: 'Howie Long',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Lyle Alzado',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Bo Jackson',
        correct: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is Al Davis?',
    answers: [{
        text: 'Current star Wie Receiver',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Current Owner',
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: "QB from the late 70's",
        correct: false
      },
      {
        text: 'Ex Owner',
        correct: true
      },
    ]
  },
];


function processResults(isCorrect) {
  if (!isCorrect) {
    return;
  }
  
  const scoreUp = parseInt(scoreUpElement.textContent, 10) || 0;

  scoreUpElement.textContent = scoreUp + 100;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Iceberg&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Iceberg', cursive;
}


/* 3 chosen variable colors that will be distributed for the game. For answer selection 
(each a color for right and wrong answers) */

:root {
  --hue-neutral: 213;
  --hue-wrong: 283;
  --hue-correct: 190;
}

body {
  --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 31%, 19%);
}


/* When answer is correct this color will become visible upon the backround selection to match correct answer */

body.correct {
  --hue: var(--hue-correct);
}


/* When answer is incorrect this color will become visible upon the background selection to match wrong answer */

body.wrong {
  --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}


/* Container layout */

.container {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #63768d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}


/* top to bottom grid with 4 options to choose from when answering question */

.btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn {
  --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 20%, 70%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: #b8f3ff;
}


/* if this button chose is 'correct' then this variable color will display */

.btn.correct {
  --hue: var(--hue-correct);
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 80%);
}


/* if this button chose is 'incorrect' then this variable color will display */

.btn.wrong {
  --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
  background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 80%);
}


/* dimensiosn for start and next button*/

.start-btn,
.next-btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}


/* Layout for buttons*/

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* grid layout for score system */

.score-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* hide selection when it is unnecessary to have visible*/

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <script defer src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Raider Quiz Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Container for questions and 4 options to choose from-->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--A start game button and a next button when anwering questions-->
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Are you a hardcore Raiders fan?<br>Find Out!</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="score-tracker" class="score-grid hide">
      <h3>Score</h3>
      <div id="score-up">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend expanding on this answer. Store your currentsScore inside the global scope of the scrips.js file. Typically it's better to store as a variable than to get it from the HTML of the page. Then move all of the Result logic into the processResults function including the css changes. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This means a lot, I am struggling to grasp these concepts.

Comment: Agree, it could be way improved, and the best practice is to store state in JavaScript not html. The code should rule it all.